# Problems with customizing css for Yii2 ListWidget

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, yii, yii2

I am new to Yii. I would like to customize css for Yii2 ListView like this:

```
ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $productsProvider,
    'options' => [
        'tag' => 'div',
        'class' => 'row',
        'id' => 'products-list-wrapper',
    ],
    'itemOptions' => [
        'class' => 'col-md-2'
    ],
    'itemView' => '_product_item.php',
    'pager' => [
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'my-custom-pagination'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

When I add bootstrap classes, e.g.: `'options' => [ 'class' => row ]`, styles do apply, but when I add my custom style rules, defined in `web/css/site.css`, they do not apply. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try looking into the rendered html in your browser to see whether
   the css file **site.css** is loaded properly and that site.css
   contains the styles defined for your custom class.
2. Make sure your asset bundles are loaded properly.
3. Your pager uses bootstrap classes for styling by default,but you can
   override the default values with your own custom styled classes.

   ```
   'pager' => [                                 
                'options' => [
                    'class' => 'my-custom-pagination',//default value is 'pagination'
                   ],
               'prevPageCssClass' => 'yourClass', // default value is  'prev'
               'activePageCssClass' => 'yourClass',// default value is 'active'
               'nextPageCssClass' => 'yourClass',// default value is 'next'
               'lastPageCssClass' => 'yourClass',// default value is 'last'
           ]
   ```

   More options available in

   http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-linkpager.html#$activePageCssClass-detail

Comment: Thanks, my site.css file was retrieved from cache, and newly added css rules were note added.